# How to get Azure Virtual Network Local IP associated with function app

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Not able to get the local IP address of the azure virtual network.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? Do you have VNet integration with function app?

Comment: Yes, I have vnet integration with function app. I want to access services by local IP in my serless function app.

Comment: Do you follow this [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)? What do you mean local IP address? the public outbound function app?

Comment: Is that link helpful? Do you still face any question?

Comment: yes @NancyXiong  that link is very helpful. Thank you:)